# How can i make my instance accessible for someone else

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

```
user_data_content=$(curl -fsSL -H "Authorization: token github_pat_11A4D3V6Y08fJxiucugdFE_M5UIeyoOskP18fydBFeUDvg1gqqJ201ARgaVztGinCkAKJHWL*****" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Mr-Marshal1/hometask2/master/user-data-script.sh)
user_data_base64=$(echo -n "$user_data_content" | base64 -w 0)
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-01bc990364452ab3e --instance-type t2.micro --user-data $user_data_base64 --key-name it-step-testvm-secretkey --security-group-ids sg-0ad3a9d1ae0f84008
```

I have this code for creating instance and I've got a problem because I use private key that is on my computer for creating. But I need to make this code in such way that someone else with their own key is able to use this code. I would be really grateful for help because I've been messing around with this for a few days and noone gave understandable answer

Comment: Keep the public keys of the people you want to enable access to this machine in some s3 location(with one public key per line). Add a script in user data which downloads these public keys and appends these to `$(HOME)/ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: Another person needs to provide me his public key?

Comment: Yes. Then they can ssh into the machine.

Answer (score 0):

When somebody connects to a Linux server using SSH, they provide a **username** and a **private key**. The server will then look in that user's `~/.authorized_keys` file to find a matching **public key**. If a match is found, the login is permitted.

When an Amazon EC2 instance is launched, there is an `ec2-user` already created on the instance. Therefore, the keypair you selected when launching the instance is stored in `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys`. So, **one option is to add additional keypairs into that file**.

Alternatively, you could [create another user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html#create-user-account) on the server (eg `marshal`) and then add the public key to: `/home/marshal/.ssh/authorized_keys`

It is generally safer for each user to **create their own keypair** since a keypair is similar to a password and should not be shared. That way, only the user has the private half of the keypair and they are the only person who can use it. Thus, you would **ask each user to create their own keypair** and provide you with the **public key**, which you would add to the appropriate `authorized_keys` file.

Quick summary:

- You can add keypairs to the `ec2-user` since it already exists, or
- Create a new user on the server and then add the keypair to that user -- This permits tighter security control per user, but requires more administrative effort